# How to get RGB values using JMagick?

Tags: java, image, imagemagick, rgb, jmagick

How to get RGB values using JMagick(a wrapper of imagemagick) ?

Comment: RGB values of what?! Of a certain pixel at a certain coordinate or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the "red" value of a specific image, on the commandline, you could use the following syntax. For the JMagick API, just look up how you'll have to translate this into API calls:

```
 identify  -format "%[fx:s.p{111,111}.r]"  input.jpg
   0.427451
```

- `fx:` is ImageMagick's *special effects image operator* that allows you to query all sorts of properties from an image, use them in a mathematical expression and apply them on the image;
- `s.` tells ImageMagick to select the current image in the sequence for applying the fx operation;
- `p{111,111}.` tells fx to use the pixel at column 111, row 111 for this operation (if you skip the pixel coordinates, fx defaults to `p{0,0}`, which is the pixel in the top left corner;
- `r` queries the *red* channel of the selected pixel;
- `0.427451` is the result: it means it is 42.7451% of the maximum value of the channel (255 for 8-bit, 65535 for 16-bit).

---

```
 identify  -format "%[fx:s.p{111,111}.z]"  input.jpg
   8
```

- `z` queries the channel depth used for the pixel. Result is 8.

You can also query the Hue, Saturation and Lightness values for a pixel after converting the image to the HSL color system:

```
identify  -colorspace hsl  -format "%[fx:s.p{111,111}.hue]"  input.jpg 
   0.538012

identify  -colorspace hsl  -format "%[fx:s.p{111,111}.saturation]"  input.jpg 
   0.53271

identify  -colorspace hsl  -format "%[fx:s.p{111,111}.lightness]"  input.jpg 
   0.790196
```